# How can I make GNU sort put uppercase letters first?

Tags: bash, sorting, gnu, textutils

I want everything else to remain identical, only have uppercase letters come first.

Answer (score 8):

This may be mostly a locale issue. If you don't need anything specific to your locale (and want your script to work the same on different systems), you may reset `LC_COLLATE` like this:

```
$ echo -e "foo\nFoo" | LC_COLLATE=C sort
Foo
foo
```

You may also set `LC_COLLATE` for the whole life-time of your script if you don't need any locale-specific collations anywhere:

```
export LC_COLLATE=C
```